# How to trigger a signal when one widget comes within some distance/area of another widget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, widget, position

I want to create an area around a widget such that if any other widgets come in that area, the widget sends a signal. Calculating the distance between the widget and every other widget might be an option, but the problem is there might be several widgets and it might be tedious. Specifically speaking, the widget is a `QLabel` and I am using `QPoint` to place the widgets. Is there an efficient way to solve the problem?

[image: Please refer the Figure]

Comment: Are both `Widget1` and `Widget2` `QLabel`'s? Are they freestanding windows, or are they placed into a layout anywhere? Do they have parents?

Comment: Both Widget1 and Widget2 are QLabel's with setPixmap("") since they will be displayed as pictures and will have a fixed size throughout the run. They are not placed in any layout. Both have a single generic QWidget as parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you want `Widget1` to emit a signal when any other widget (e.g., `Widget2`) is moved such that it lands within the region of interest around `Widget1`. One way to do this is override the *moving* widgets' `moveEvent()` handler functions to notify `Widget1` of their new position.

This handler is called after a widget has been moved, and is already at the new position. The simplest thing might be to just stick a custom signal at the top of this, before calling the parent's implementation of the handler. Something like:

```
MyWidget::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *ev) {
    emit widgetMoved(ev->pos()); // emit signal with this widget's new position
    QLabel::moveEvent(ev);
}
```

This requires subclassing `QLabel`, declaring the `widgetMoved()` signal, and reimplementing the handler. You could also send the `this` pointer in the signal, so that `Widget1` knows immediately which widget sent the event. (This isn't necessary, since you can get a pointer to the sending widget with `QObject::sender()`, but it might be easier.)

Then write a slot in `Widget1`, connected to this signal, that computes the distance between this moved widget and itself, and emit a signal if that distance is less than whatever the ROI size is.